# MVC List<> do not pass data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, razor

My problem is:
When i try to pass from GetMethod to PostMethod List of objects and number is lower than 200 everything is OK, but when is bigger than 200 it send null

```cs
[HttpPost]
[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]
public ActionResult Nadgodziny2(List<View_Grafik> ListGraf)
{

}
```

```
@model List<View_Grafik> 

<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item[i].zdarzenie, new { style = "width: 50px;", onclick = functionName2 , @class = classNameB} ) 
</td>
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item[i].komentarz , new { style = "width: 50px;", onclick = functionName3 , @class = classNameC})
</td>
<td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(item => item[i].blad, new { style = "width: 50px;", onclick = functionName1 })
</td>
```

I have try everything, nothing work, I'm expecting help ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "pass from GetMethod to PostMethod"? I don't see a Get method

Comment: What I understand you to be saying is that you are posting to your Post method from a form, but when you post more than 200 items worth of data, `ListGraf` is null. But you don't get an exception. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer I have to add:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => {
    options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```